# Nested objects without generics support: workarounds

Tags: forms, scala, generics, playframework

Hitting a catch 22 situation due to lack of generics support in Play template layer.

I have several shopping cart screens that all require a User and a Payment + optional custom fields.

```
case class Conference(
  user: User,
  payment: Payment
  ... custom fields here
)
```

So, rather than duplicating all the user and payment form fields per shop cart model, I've consolidated as above and implemented nested forms.

Now, the problem occurs at the template layer where there is to-date no generics support.

The parent/container form pulls in nested child forms like so:

```
@(_form: Form[Conference])

@user.nested( UserForm.form.fill(_form.get.user) )
@payment.nested( PaymentForm.form.fill(_form.get.payment) )
```

and then the child User form looks like:

```
@(_form: Form[User])

@inputText(_form("user.firstName"), '_label-> "First Name*", 'class-> "required")
@inputText(_form("user.lastName"), '_label-> "Last Name*", 'class-> "required")
...
```

and the User model:

```
case class User(firstName: String, lastName: String ...)
```

How do I access "user.firstName", "user.lastName", etc. when there is no user property in the User model? The Play Form apply method is:

```
def apply(key: String): Field = Field(
    this,
    key,
    constraints.get(key).getOrElse(Nil),
    formats.get(key),
    errors.collect { case e if e.key == key => e },
    data.get(key))
```

Basically it's going to look for property `data.user.firstName` which is obviously not going to work.

I've thought about adding a user property to User model:

```
case class User(firstName: String, lastName: String ...) {
  val user: User
}
```

but not sure if that will work and/or wreak havoc with case class companion object apply/unapply.

At any rate, given the lack of generics, what's a viable solution to the problem?

Were generics supported we could pass in an upper bound and everything would be rosy:

```
trait CartOrder {
  user: User,
  payment: Payment
}
case class Conference(...) extends CartOrder
```

and then nested User form is passed an instance that contains a user property and we're good

```
@[T <: CartOrder](_form: Form[T])
@inputText(_form("user.firstName"), '_label-> "First Name*", 'class-> "required")
...
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I get your problem Re: generics. Couldn't you just parameterize it as Form[CartOrder] then?

As an aside, regarding the user problem. One thing you could do is separate your User Mapping from the User Form. You could then reuse the mapping in your Conference Form and then in the User Form use userMapping.withPrefix("user") so that the access keys are consistent.

Comment: Right, I've actually been working on doing just that; however it's not as simple as specifying Form[CartOrder], get an error: "class play.api.data.Form is invariant in type T". So the compiler accepts that Conference derives from CartOrder, but Play defines Form[T] and not a Form[+T]

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't know it was invariant. Another thing I can suggest to you is, to have one Form/Mapping of type CartOrder, and then use optional mappings for all the optional fields and then in the main mapping function, return the appropriate concrete type. It's not particularly elegant though

Comment: I'll post my solution in a bit, basically you have to pass in the super type of Conference, Subscription, etc. cart models, which I am calling CartModel, or CartOrder, whatever. This super type itself must contain the form mapping for user and payment. It's not that bad, but not nearly as elegant as straight up T <: SuperType and done with it, no boilerplate at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the dilly-o follows thusly (chime in if you have a better way):

play.api.data.Form[T] is invariant, so no dice passing in the super type of Conference (i.e. CartOrder) to the User form. In other words, this blows up:

```
// user.scala.html
@(_form: Form[CartOrder])
```

Basically you have to pass in an instance that itself is Form mappable.

To workaround the template layer fun house, I have implemented the following hack:

```
case class CartModel(user: User, payment: Payment)
```

**EDIT**
gets better, added in a `bind` helper to CartForm mapper below, which makes for clean syntax in views

```
object CartForm {
  import play.api.data.Forms._  
  val form = 
    Form( mapping(
      'user -> UserForm.mapper,
      'payment -> PaymentForm.mapper )(CartModel.apply)(CartModel.unapply) )

  // hey, generics!
  def bind[T <: Form[_ <: CartContract]](t: T) =
    t.value map{x=> form.fill( CartModel(x.user, x.payment) )} getOrElse form
}
```

and then in the Conference parent form, pull in User form fields like so:

```
@user.nested( CartForm.bind(_form) )
```

and the User form then receives:

```
@(_form: Form[CartModel])
```

A good deal of boilerplate is eliminated with nested forms in general, so overall, progress. Would be great not to rely on the intermediary Form mapper, but this is as good as I can come up with for now...

Answer (score 2):

If type safety isn't a concern (`Form`s aren't all that type safe to begin with), you can just use `Form[_]` as the parameter type for your nested templates.

---

If you do want type safety, one option is to make a wrapper class for Form that is covariant and use that in place of Form. One implementation is:

```
package views.html

import play.api.data._
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue

object FormView {
    implicit def formToFormView[A, T >: A](form: Form[A]): FormView[T] = new FormView[T] {
        type F = A
        def realForm = form
    }
}

trait FormView[+T] {
    type F <: T

    def realForm: Form[F]

    def apply(key: String): Field = realForm(key)

    def constraints : Map[String, Seq[(String, Seq[Any])]] = realForm.constraints

    def data: Map[String, String] = realForm.data

    def error(key: String): Option[FormError] = realForm.error(key)

    def errors(key: String): Seq[FormError] = realForm.errors(key)

    def errors: Seq[FormError] = realForm.errors

    def errorsAsJson: JsValue = realForm.errorsAsJson

    def get: T = realForm.get

    def formats: Map[String, (String, Seq[Any])] = realForm.formats

    def globalError: Option[FormError] = realForm.globalError

    def globalErrors: Seq[FormError] = realForm.globalErrors

    def hasErrors: Boolean = realForm.hasErrors

    def hasGlobalErrors: Boolean = realForm.hasGlobalErrors

    override def hashCode: Int = realForm.hashCode

    def mapping: Mapping[F] = realForm.mapping

    def value: Option[T] = realForm.value
}
```

Now instead of your templates being

```
@(_form: Form[CartOrder])
```

which won't work because of invariance, you can use

```
@(_form: FormView[CartOrder])
```

and you can simply pass in any `Form[T]` where `T` is a subtype of `CartOrder` like

```
@user.nested(_form)
```

the implicits will handle the conversion from Form to FormView

A complete example can be found at: https://github.com/thatsmydoing/formtest

Comment: +1 for the creative wrapper approach. Curious, in what way is Play's Form implementation not type safe? Form[_] obviously throws type safety out the window, so not taking that route.

Comment: No matter what key you give to form.apply(), it will give you a `Field` even if the key does not exist. It's useful for templates since you can just use `Form[_]` and it would still work. Also, if you have `Form`s that return the same type, but have different keys, they're not exactly the "same" type.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you want

```
@(_form: Form[_ <: CartOrder])
```

instead of suggested

```
@[T <: CartOrder](_form: Form[T])
```